# I want that my player(character) find the node on which he standing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> I want that my player(character) find the node on which he standing. [image: this is my unity window image]

> FindingNode.cs

```
using System;
```

using UnityEngine;

public class FindingNode : MonoBehaviour
{

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    Action action = () =>
    {
        Debug.Log("vikas");
    };

    Action action1 = () =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Singh");

    };
    if (other.gameObject.name == "node(1)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(2)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(3)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(4)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(5)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(6)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(7)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(8)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(9)")
    {
        Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
        popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.name == "node(10)")
  
    else
        Debug.Log("not working");
}
```

}

> it's showing only "not working" output in Console.
> Rigidbody is added to the nodes;
> this is interface of monopoly game. if player is able to find the node then the popup show according to the node.

Comment: Firstly your node names seem to have spaces betwen node and the bracket. Secondly you could have juat debugged the name. Next all tour node actions seem the same. Last. Learn switch statements

Comment: You obviously got a problem with the naming. But all the calls are the same so whatever you stand on, it'll do the same. Worth mentioning that your collision method may be called multiple times and call for different nodes when overlapping two or more. This is because the physics needs penetration and it means many hitting points. Finally forget about the switch advice, it wont make any difference in your case except longer code.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `[unityscript]` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in previous Unity versions and is long**deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`. Also this is not specifically related to VisualStudio at all

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use switch cases in this case.

The code should look somehow like this:

```
switch(other.gameObject.name) {
   case "node(1)":
     Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
     popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
   break;

   case "node(2)":
      Popup popup = UIController.Instance.CreatePopup();
      popup.Init(UIController.Instance.MainCanvas, action, action1);
   break;
default:    
break;
}
```

...and so on...

I hope this will work for you, good luck.

Comment: How's a switch making any difference? Why not a dictionary<string, Action> then?

Comment: It doesn't but maybe it would work with cases. Or you can try with `OnTriggerEnter` and is the trigger box on the nodes checked?